# return outside of function with a global variable

Tags: python

For my code an assignment is requesting
"a return statement returns to the statement in the main() function that is after the call to the play game() function".

I tried entering the return statement after the rand variable and received the error
return outside of function. I would like to understand the correct way to use the return statement to
complete the assignment

```
def play_game():
  return
  global rand
  rand=random.randint(1,10)
  play_game()
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The code here doesn't make much sense. Anything after `return` is not executed and might as well be removed. Generally, avoid `global` and do `return random.randint(1, 10)`. If you have a textbook on Python basics which discusses functions, I suggest reading through it carefully, since there are fundamental misunderstandings here that lead me to believe you're sort of trying things at random without understanding (totally fine, but it's a good sign that it's time to step back and revisit some basics). See https://realpython.com/python-return-statement/ for example.

Comment: What's the purpose of the global variable? It's not needed for learning about return statements. What is the full assignment? Where's the main() function that's mentioned?

Comment: 1. You cannot have a `return` outside of a function. 2. Be careful with global variables. They are a common cause of difficult to find bugs. I recommend using parameters and return values instead. 3. Your code example doesn't define the `main(0` function so we are missing a lot of context for your assignment. Please show a more complete example so that we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Eror "Return outside of function" can occur because lines are not properly indented.

Observe this wonderfully crafted code:

```py
def play_game():
    # im gonna do NOTHING!
    pass
return "hey, buddy!"
```

It does not, in fact compile. The result of trying to run the above:

```
    return "hey, buddy!"
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function
```

This is because `return "hey, buddy!"` is not indented correctly. It is **outside** the function definition `play_game()`.

Fix indentation, and you fix the error:

```py
def play_game():
    # im gonna do NOTHING!
    pass
    return "hey, buddy!"
```

Comment: I wanted to add a return statement that returns to the statement in the main(function), that is after the call to the play game() function. I tried the following  def play_game():
      print("Playing game...")
      return
           
      randint(x,y)
rand = random.randint(1, 10)

def main():
      print("Starting...")
      play_game()
      print("Finishing.")           But my print statements do not print. Just do not understand

Answer (score 0):

> a return statement returns to the statement in the main() function that is after the call to the play game() function

Note that this is an explanation, not a request. If your question is what does this explanation mean, we can break it down.

First of all, you need a `main()` function:

```
def main():
    pass
```

Second of all, it says that the `main()` function should call the `play_game()` function:

```
def play_game():
    pass

def main():
    play_game()
```

Next, the `play_game()` function needs a return statement:

```
def play_game():
    return

def main():
    play_game()
```

Often you return a value from a function, but you don't give enough information here for me to guess what that should be, so I will just have a bare `return` in this example.

Finally, the `main()` function needs something after the `play_game()` function. We'll just add a `print()` statement. While we are add it, we will add a `print()` to `play_game()` to understand how things work:

```
def play_game():
    print("Playing game...")
    return

def main():
    print("Starting...")
    play_game()
    print("Finishing.")
```

If you run this short program, you will see the output as

```
Starting...
Playing game...
Finishing.
```

As you see the `return` causes execution to continue in `main()` after `play_game()` was called.

I hope this helps.

p.s. I don't understand what the global variable has to do with anything. If you need more help, please edit your question with more details to help us understand where you are stuck.

Comment: def play_game():  
    global rand
rand=random.randint(1,10)
return  rand     
     
def main():
  play_game()

Comment: def play_game():  
    global rand
rand=random.randint(1,10)
return  rand     
     
def main():
  play_game()
  print('finishing')
  
while True:
  guess=int(input('Enter a number between 1 and 10   ')) 

  
  if guess < rand:
      print('Too low')

  elif guess > rand:
      print('Too high')

  else:
        print('You guessed it')
        I added the return to the code but still getting return outside of function. Could I ask for a little more help please.

Comment: @Michelle see my answer. Return outside of function is straightforward to fix.

Comment: @Michelle Please edit your question.  Formatting code in a comment is not supported, so it is impossible to read.

Comment: @Michelle As rv.kvetch says in their answer, you most likely have not indented the `return` statement properly. It is impossible to tell from teh code in your comment here, though. Also, since you are doing `return rand`, there is no reason to do `global rand`. Instead, you should do `rand = play_game()` in `main()`. I recommend that you read more about return values and how to use them.